# Seagate backplus desktop drive 4 TB is not recognized in my dell inspiron 15r 5520 laptop bios

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, external-hard-drive, dell-inspiron

I am using the windows 7 home premium 64 bit OS, the drive gets detected& i see it in the MY COMPUTER area but not in the bios. I even updated my bios through the dell website. I want to use it as a bootable device. Or should i change like from LEGACY to UEFI mode ? step by step guidance would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of partition are you using currently MBR or UEFI?

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems as if you reach the limmit with the 4TB drive. I think the limmit of BIOS based clients is 2.1TB or so. I would recommend switching to UEFI as UEFI allows you to boot with disks larger than 2TB. Almost forgot, you need to format the disk GPT otherwise you wont be able to make use of the 4TB. The only problem with that is, that you cannot boot from a GPT converted disk, except with windows 7. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx) article:

*GPT disks are self-identifying. All the information needed to interpret the partitioning scheme of a GPT disk is completely contained in structures in specified locations on the physical media.*

So the OS needs to know how to read GPT disks, which windows 7 does.

I would recommend that you create two 2TB partitions. One as boot-disk the other for DATA.

Also check here:

[Installing Windows Server 2008 on disk larger than 2TB](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/97ff7042-5b94-44cd-9fa7-2c0373e8f037/installing-server-2008-with-a-partition-larger-than-2t-raid-10-mirrored)

[Installing windows 7 on a 4tb hard drive](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/294757-31-installing-windows-hard-drive)

[Do I need UEFI enabled in BIOS for a 4TB external, non-boot disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/610693/do-i-need-uefi-enabled-in-bios-for-a-4tb-external-non-boot-disk)

Comment: check the first comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/97ff7042-5b94-44cd-9fa7-2c0373e8f037/installing-server-2008-with-a-partition-larger-than-2t-raid-10-mirrored

Comment: have you ever tried it before? because windows 8 wont allow you to do so. I tried it myself on this very PC. I converted it to GPT and Windows grayed the option of installing windows on it out.

Comment: I was able to install Windows 8 on a 4TB HDD without a problem.  The author's problem is something else considering they don't even see the device and they should.

Comment: My apology @Ramhound it seems you were right about windows 7. I updated my Answer. But its funny because it didn't work with my setup :S

Comment: That would be something we would have to explore in your own question or the chat.

Comment: Jup some day when I reinstall Windows on this machine. :)

Comment: Lets put it this way.  Windows 8 has to support it because UEFI doesn't directly support MBR.  Of course most systems automatically go into a Legacy Mode which does support it.  All new Windows 8 systems must have a UEFI Bios therefore Windows 8 supports booting off GPT partitions.